# SQL results to Outlook VCard?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I need to export SQL records to outlook vcards, so 1 vcard per result row returned.  Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
DECLARE @crlf char(2)
SET @crlf = CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)

SELECT 
    'BEGIN:VCARD' + @crlf
    + COALESCE ('N:' + COALESCE (Last, '') + ';'
    + COALESCE (First, '') + ';'
    + COALESCE (Mi, '') + @crlf, '')
    + COALESCE ('FN:' + FullName + @crlf, '')
    + COALESCE ('TITLE:' + Title + @crlf, '')
    + COALESCE ('ORG:' + Company + @crlf, '')
    + COALESCE ('TEL;WORK;VOICE:' + PhoneWork + @crlf, '')
    + COALESCE ('TEL;WORK;FAX:' + FaxWork + @crlf, '')
    + COALESCE ('TEL;HOME;VOICE:' + [PhoneHome] + @crlf, '')
    + COALESCE ('TEL;HOME;FAX:' + [FaxHome] + @crlf, '')
    + COALESCE ('TEL;CELL;VOICE:' + [PhoneMobile] + @crlf, '')
    + COALESCE ('TEL;PAGER;VOICE:' + [Pager] + @crlf, '')
    + 'ADR;WORK:;;' + COALESCE ([Address], '') + ';'
    + COALESCE ([City], '') + ';' + COALESCE ([State], '') + ';'
    + COALESCE ([Zip], '') + @crlf
    + COALESCE ('EMAIL;PREF;INTERNET:' + [email] + @crlf, '')
    + 'REV:' + { fn REPLACE({ fn REPLACE(
    { fn REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar, GETDATE(), 120), '-', '')
    }, ':', '') }, ' ', 'T') } + 'Z'+ @crlf
    + 'END:VCARD' + @crlf AS vcard
FROM 
    yourTable
```